# Multicast socket problems on Windows 7

Tags: sockets, multicast

I've setup a UDP server, and joined a multicast group on both localhost interface and the physical ethernet, to be able to receive multicasts from 127.0.0.1 and 192.168.78.* (example).

According to docs, the destination interface for a multicast message is determined through the source address, and I have a client sending messages, but sometimes localhost interface is chosen, and sometimes the ethernet interface. I.e. in the former case the source address is 127.0.0.1.

Question: How can I force a datagram socket to always send multicast messages to the physical interface ? (i.e. having a source address of 192.168.78.xx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> According to docs, the destination interface for a multicast message is determined through the source address

No. It is determined by the route to the multicast address given by looking up the IP routing tables, unless you use the `IP_MULTICAST_IF` option, which sets the default interface for outgoing multicasts.

> I have a client sending messages, but sometimes localhost interface is chosen, and sometimes the ethernet interface. I.e. in the former case the source address is 127.0.0.1.
>
> Question: How can I force a datagram socket to always send multicast messages to the physical interface ? (i.e. having a source address of 192.168.78.xx)

With the option mentioned above.

Source: Stevens *et al.,* *Unix Network Programming,* 3rd edition, §21.6.

Comment: Thank you! I think that IP_MULTICAST_IF is exactly what I was after.

Comment: It is interesting though that Win7 seems (per observation) to choose interface randomly.

Comment: Hard to see why, but anything is possible from that vendor. Stevens is specifically talking about BSD Unix.

Comment: Unfortunately the IP_MULTICAST_IF seems to be a no-op on Windows, I still can get multicast messages routed through local interface :(

Comment: I found that on Windows I needed to explicitly bind to each interface address, and send the multicast on each interface.